# Make components out of axios object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, api, axios

I made this simple example where I receive a object with objects inside with Axios. My question is what approach could I use to create a different component of each Axios result and render then independently. As I would like to use them in the different places of my webapp.

```
class apitest extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      btcticker: {},
      ethticker: {},
      trxticker: {},
      xrpticker: {},
      eosticker: {},
      bchticker: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemulti?fsyms=BTC,ETH,XRP,BCH,EOS,TRX&tsyms=EUR,CHANGE&api_key=xxx"
      )
      .then(res => {
        const BTCEUR = res.data.BTC;
        const ETHEUR = res.data.ETH;
        const BCHEUR = res.data.BCH;
        const EOSEUR = res.data.EOS;
        const TRXEUR = res.data.TRX;
        const XRPEUR = res.data.XRP;
        console.log(BTCEUR);
        console.log(ETHEUR);
        console.log(BCHEUR);
        console.log(EOSEUR);
        console.log(TRXEUR);
        console.log(XRPEUR);
        this.setState({ btcticker: BTCEUR });
        this.setState({ ethticker: ETHEUR });
        this.setState({ bchticker: BCHEUR });
        this.setState({ eosticker: EOSEUR });
        this.setState({ trxticker: TRXEUR });
        this.setState({ xrpticker: XRPEUR });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="test">
        {Object.keys(this.state.btcticker).map(key => (
          <div id="crypto-container">
            <span className="left">{key}</span>
            <span className="right">
              <NumberFormat
                value={this.state.btcticker.EUR}
                displayType={"text"}
                decimalPrecision={2}
                thousandSeparator={true}
                prefix={"€"}
              />
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default apitest;
```

Comment: Here's example code: https://codesandbox.io/s/2vz1p9676n

Comment: This is amazing thanks! But how do I make that every ticker is separate ? As I want to place them in a slider one by one.

Comment: I updated the sandbox; now there's a fully autonomous Ticker component.

Answer (score 0):

You should make this component where you are making the call the parent of your other components.  Then pass to each component just the portion of the data it needs for its view.  Alternatively you could use something like Redux with redux saga to create a global store where you can keep cached data, then connect each component to the store so it can get the data it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code: codesandbox.io/s/2vz1p9676n  Chris G made a solution which is perfect